# App stops responding to user input whilst task is ongoing. Any way to prevent this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When it gets to a certain line of code in Flite, it takes about 2 minutes to get through that line, converting what's written into text-to-speech to be played back.

During this process, the app stops responding to any user input, dealing with it once it's finished with the code from Flite. Obviously this is an inconvenience. Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 5):

You should do any long processing in a background thread, not in the UI run loop, using something like NSOperationQueue, plus a completion callback to inform the UI when the processing is done.

Comment: And will this make the processing go slower at all?

Comment: @Andrew : Speed will depend on what else is going on, in the UI thread, or in any background threads, or other apps.  iOS is a multi-tasking OS, but currently running on a uni-processor, so everything has to share that one resource.